# Replace class content using php

Tags: php, html

I want to replace string from specific classes from HTML.
           In HTML there is other content which I don't want to change.
           In below code want to change data on class one and three only, class two content should be as it is.
           I need to this in dynamic way.

```
<div class="one"> I want to change this </div> 
<div class="two"> I don't want to change this </div> 
<div class="three"> I want to change this </div>
```

Comment: <div class="one">
        I want to change this
        </div>
        <div class="two">
        I don't want to change this
        </div>
        <div class="three">
        I want to change this
        </div>

Comment: you know that PHP is a server side language? So you cannot use it to modify the DOM after it has been rendered by the browser. You should use Javascript for that

Comment: Yes, but I need in a way like.We have main template editor where there is two types on content one is editable and one is non editable from here main admin can update both.So on updating here non editable text which can be updated by master admin only should get update in all it's child editor

Comment: I want to this replacement in at time of save main template in controller.Not after rendering on browser

Answer (score 0):

Dom functions are helpful

[php manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom)

```
//your html file content
$str = '...<div class="one"> I want to change this </div>
<div class="two"> I don\'t want to change this </div>
<div class="three"> I want to change this </div>... ';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($str);

$domXpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

//query the nodes matched
$list = $domXpath->query('//div[@class!="two"]');
if ($list->length > 0) {
    foreach ($list as $node) {
        //change node value
        $node->nodeValue = 'Content changed!';
    }
}

//get the result
$new_str = $dom->saveHTML();

var_dump($new_str);
```

Comment: Yes, but can be with html tags too?

Comment: Yes, but can be with html tags too? Like full html with <p style="color:red">Changed Content</p>

Comment: No, assign a string contains HTML Tag will be escaped.  XPath query result is a DOMNodeList object that holds all matched DOMNode objects. A DOMNode object may contains child nodes too. If you want to exactly change the target content, try to write the right xpath query is better.

Comment: https://devdocs.io/php/class.domnode check it in PHP docs